# How do I override the default behavior of select: within jQuery UI Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following:

```
$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    var parameters = {
      isoalpha2: '<%=Session["BusinessCountry"].ToString()%>',
      prefixText: request.term
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/AtomicService/Assets.asmx/GetCitiesWithState")%>',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
      success: function (data) {
        response($.each(data.d, function (index, value) {
          return {
            label: value.slice(value.indexOf(',')),
            value: parseInt(value.split(',')[0])
          }
        }));
      }

    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  delay: 50,
  select: function (event, ui) {
    var city = ui.item.label.split(',')[0];
    var state = ui.item.label.split(',')[1];
    alert(city);
    alert(state);
    $('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>').val(city);
    $('#<%=txtState.ClientID%>').val(state);
  },
});
```

It's all happy days, except when I select an item from the autocomplete list I'd like to not have autocomplete populate the `$('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>')` element. How do I do it? I saw `.insertAfter`, is that something I should look at?

Help appreciated.

Comment: I assume this includes ASP.NET code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try returning `false` from the [`select` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select):

```
...
select: function(event, ui) {
    var city = ui.item.label.split(',')[0];
    var state = ui.item.label.split(',')[1];
    alert(city);
    alert(state);
    $('#<%=txtCity.ClientID%>').val(city);
    $('#<%=txtState.ClientID%>').val(state);
    return false;
},
```

From the documentation (select event):

> Triggered when an item is selected
>   from the menu; ui.item refers to the
>   selected item. The default action of
>   select is to replace the text field's
>   value with the value of the selected
>   item. **Canceling this event prevents
>   the value from being updated, but does
>   not prevent the menu from closing.**

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrg9A/)

Answer (score 3):

While it probably won't make a difference here, instead of returning false, you should be saying event.preventDefault

See [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

It's bad practice to always stop propagation of the event when you don't need to.